# Java graphics JApplet

Tags: java, swing, graphics, japplet

I'm currently working on a program which is for school. We have to make an Applet and I have opted for JApplet. For some reason, the panel which I am using to display a specific string will not show. What might be the issue here? Please point me in the right direction. Also, I looked at a few a tutorials, some suggested that I have "start", "stop" and "destory" methods and some didn't. Do any of these methods have an effect on why my JPanel won't show the graphic?

Thank you

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Shape extends JApplet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // making the radiobuttons for the shape choices 
    JRadioButton squareButton = new JRadioButton("Square",true);
    JRadioButton ovalButton = new JRadioButton("Oval",false);
    JRadioButton rectangleButton = new JRadioButton("Rectangle",false);
    JRadioButton triangleButton = new JRadioButton("Triangle",false);

    // making radiobuttons for the color choices
    JRadioButton redButton = new JRadioButton("Red",true);
    JRadioButton blueButton = new JRadioButton("Blue",false);
    JRadioButton greenButton = new JRadioButton("Green",false);
    JRadioButton yellowButton = new JRadioButton("Yellow",false);

    // making buttons draw and animate
    JButton drawButton = new JButton("Draw!");
    JButton animateButton = new JButton("Animate!");

    // making JTextFields for length and width
    JTextField lengthField = new JTextField("Enter a length",15);
    JTextField widthField = new JTextField("Enter a width",15);

    // making JPanel, in which the radiobuttons will go01
    JPanel shapePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel colorPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
    drawPanel dPanel;

    ButtonGroup shapeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup colorGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    // variables that will dictates the shape, size and color
    int length = 200;
    int width = 200;
    Color color = Color.RED;
    String shape = "square";

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // setting layout for the applet
        setSize(680,480);

        // setting the layout for the shapePanel - gridlayout 2 rows, 2 cols and space of 5
        shapePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,5,5));

        // adding a border to the shapePanel to indicate to the user what it does "titledBorder"
        shapePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose a shape"));

        // setting layout for the color panel - gridlayout 2 rows, 2 cols and space of 5
        colorPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,5,5));

        // adding a border to the  colorPanel to indicate to the user what it does "titledBorder"
        colorPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose a color"));

        // setting the layout for the buttonPanel - gridlayout 1 row, 2 cols and space of 5
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));

        // adding a color border
        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 2));

        // setting the layout of the textField - gridlayout 1 row, 2 cols and space of 5
        textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));

        // adding some attributes for lengthField and widthField
        lengthField.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,12));
        lengthField.setForeground(new Color(150,150,150));

        widthField.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,12));
        widthField.setForeground(new Color(150,150,150));

        // using shapegroup to organize the JRadioButtons
        shapeGroup.add(squareButton);
        shapeGroup.add(ovalButton);
        shapeGroup.add(rectangleButton);
        shapeGroup.add(triangleButton);

        // using colorgroup to organize the color radiobuttons
        colorGroup.add(redButton);
        colorGroup.add(blueButton);
        colorGroup.add(greenButton);
        colorGroup.add(yellowButton);

        // add the shape buttons to the panel so they appear in a square form 
        shapePanel.add(squareButton);
        shapePanel.add(ovalButton);
        shapePanel.add(rectangleButton);
        shapePanel.add(triangleButton);

        // adding color buttons to the color panel
        colorPanel.add(redButton);
        colorPanel.add(blueButton);
        colorPanel.add(greenButton);
        colorPanel.add(yellowButton);

        // adding jbuttons
        buttonPanel.add(drawButton);
        buttonPanel.add(animateButton);

        // adding textfields to the textPanel
        textPanel.add(lengthField);
        textPanel.add(widthField);

        dPanel  = new drawPanel();

        // adding panels to the applet
        add(shapePanel);
        add(colorPanel);
        add(buttonPanel);
        add(textPanel);
        add(dPanel);

        // adding focus listener to lengthField and widthField
        lengthField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                lengthField.setText("");
                lengthField.setForeground(Color.black);
            }

            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {}

        });

        widthField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                widthField.setText("");
                widthField.setForeground(Color.black);
            }

            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {}

        });

        drawButton.addActionListener(new drawListener());

    }

    // when the person presses paint, this will be executed to paint the specific shape, color with the width and length
    class drawListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int mylength = 5; 
            int mywidth = 5;

            try {
                mylength = Integer.parseInt(lengthField.getText());;
                mywidth = Integer.parseInt(widthField.getText());;
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ex,"",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            if((mylength > 200 || mylength < 5)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure the number is above 5 and less than 200", 
                        "Invalid length message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }else if((mywidth > 200 || mywidth < 5)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure the number is above 5 and less than 200", 
                        "Invalid width message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }else {
                length = mylength;
                width = mywidth;

                // checking which color button is selected
                if(redButton.isSelected()) {
                    color = Color.RED;
                }else if(blueButton.isSelected()) {
                    color = Color.BLUE;
                }else if(greenButton.isSelected()) {
                    color = Color.GREEN;
                }else if(yellowButton.isSelected()) {
                    color = Color.YELLOW;
                }

                // checking which shape has been selected
                if(rectangleButton.isSelected()) {
                    shape = "rectangle";
                }else if(triangleButton.isSelected()) {
                    shape = "triangle";
                }else if(ovalButton.isSelected()) {
                    shape = "oval";
                }else if(squareButton.isSelected()) {
                    shape = "square";
                }

                //System.out.printf("%3d %3d %s %s \n",length,width,shape,color);

            }

        }
    }

    // This will be used to do the painting
    class drawPanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        //Paint Method
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(Color.black);

            g2.drawString("My awesome string", 200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JPanel` with no components has a default size of 0x0.  Try this source:

```
// <applet code=Shape width=640 height=480></applet>
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Shape extends JApplet {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // making the radiobuttons for the shape choices
    JRadioButton squareButton = new JRadioButton("Square",true);
    JRadioButton ovalButton = new JRadioButton("Oval",false);
    JRadioButton rectangleButton = new JRadioButton("Rectangle",false);
    JRadioButton triangleButton = new JRadioButton("Triangle",false);

    // making radiobuttons for the color choices
    JRadioButton redButton = new JRadioButton("Red",true);
    JRadioButton blueButton = new JRadioButton("Blue",false);
    JRadioButton greenButton = new JRadioButton("Green",false);
    JRadioButton yellowButton = new JRadioButton("Yellow",false);

    // making buttons draw and animate
    JButton drawButton = new JButton("Draw!");
    JButton animateButton = new JButton("Animate!");

    // making JTextFields for length and width
    JTextField lengthField = new JTextField("Enter a length",15);
    JTextField widthField = new JTextField("Enter a width",15);

    // making JPanel, in which the radiobuttons will go01
    JPanel shapePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel colorPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
    drawPanel dPanel;

    ButtonGroup shapeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    ButtonGroup colorGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    // variables that will dictates the shape, size and color
    int length = 200;
    int width = 200;
    Color color = Color.RED;
    String shape = "square";

    public void init() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // setting layout for the applet
        // This is set by HTML!
        //setSize(680,480);

        // setting the layout for the shapePanel - gridlayout 2 rows, 2 cols and space of 5
        shapePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,5,5));

        // adding a border to the shapePanel to indicate to the user what it does "titledBorder"
        shapePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose a shape"));

        // setting layout for the color panel - gridlayout 2 rows, 2 cols and space of 5
        colorPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,5,5));

        // adding a border to the  colorPanel to indicate to the user what it does "titledBorder"
        colorPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose a color"));

        // setting the layout for the buttonPanel - gridlayout 1 row, 2 cols and space of 5
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));

        // adding a color border
        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 2));

        // setting the layout of the textField - gridlayout 1 row, 2 cols and space of 5
        textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));

        // adding some attributes for lengthField and widthField
        lengthField.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,12));
        lengthField.setForeground(new Color(150,150,150));

        widthField.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,12));
        widthField.setForeground(new Color(150,150,150));

        // using shapegroup to organize the JRadioButtons
        shapeGroup.add(squareButton);
        shapeGroup.add(ovalButton);
        shapeGroup.add(rectangleButton);
        shapeGroup.add(triangleButton);

        // using colorgroup to organize the color radiobuttons
        colorGroup.add(redButton);
        colorGroup.add(blueButton);
        colorGroup.add(greenButton);
        colorGroup.add(yellowButton);

        // add the shape buttons to the panel so they appear in a square form
        shapePanel.add(squareButton);
        shapePanel.add(ovalButton);
        shapePanel.add(rectangleButton);
        shapePanel.add(triangleButton);

        // adding color buttons to the color panel
        colorPanel.add(redButton);
        colorPanel.add(blueButton);
        colorPanel.add(greenButton);
        colorPanel.add(yellowButton);

        // adding jbuttons
        buttonPanel.add(drawButton);
        buttonPanel.add(animateButton);

        // adding textfields to the textPanel
        textPanel.add(lengthField);
        textPanel.add(widthField);

        dPanel  = new drawPanel();
        dPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,300));

        // adding panels to the applet
        add(shapePanel);
        add(colorPanel);
        add(buttonPanel);
        add(textPanel);
        add(dPanel);

        // adding focus listener to lengthField and widthField
        lengthField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                lengthField.setText("");
                lengthField.setForeground(Color.black);
            }

            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {}

        });

        widthField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                widthField.setText("");
                widthField.setForeground(Color.black);
            }

            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {}

        });

        drawButton.addActionListener(new drawListener());

    }

    // when the person presses paint, this will be executed to paint the specific shape, color with the width and length
    class drawListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int mylength = 5;
            int mywidth = 5;

            try {
                mylength = Integer.parseInt(lengthField.getText());;
                mywidth = Integer.parseInt(widthField.getText());;
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ex,"",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            if((mylength > 200 || mylength < 5)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure the number is above 5 and less than 200",
                        "Invalid length message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }else if((mywidth > 200 || mywidth < 5)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure the number is above 5 and less than 200",
                        "Invalid width message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }else {
                length = mylength;
                width = mywidth;

                // checking which color button is selected
                if(redButton.isSelected()) {
                    color = Color.RED;
                }else if(blueButton.isSelected()) {
                    color = Color.BLUE;
                }else if(greenButton.isSelected()) {
                    color = Color.GREEN;
                }else if(yellowButton.isSelected()) {
                    color = Color.YELLOW;
                }

                // checking which shape has been selected
                if(rectangleButton.isSelected()) {
                    shape = "rectangle";
                }else if(triangleButton.isSelected()) {
                    shape = "triangle";
                }else if(ovalButton.isSelected()) {
                    shape = "oval";
                }else if(squareButton.isSelected()) {
                    shape = "square";
                }

                //System.out.printf("%3d %3d %s %s \n",length,width,shape,color);

            }

        }
    }

    // This will be used to do the painting
    class drawPanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        //Paint Method
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(Color.black);

            g2.drawString("My awesome string", 200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you sir, are a life saver. Thank you very much. I was wondering if you could please remove this code, as this is for a project and I don't want to have someone copy it. Thank you once again.

Comment: *"I was wondering if you could please remove this code,"*  I could, but won't.  That is not how SO works.  If you need private solutions, hire a private tutor.

Comment: @user681159: so you're saying in effect that it's OK for you to borrow this code, but not OK for others to do the same? What's with that? Are you better or more important than others who could benefit from this? Or is the reason instead that you want to submit this code for your assignment as if you wrote it. Either way, this stinks.

Comment: @user681159: I've rolled back  your question so that your original code shows. Let's keep things above board for your instructor.

Comment: *"You can keep it on."*  <DWS>Oh, thank you kind sir.</DWS> *"Just say it nicely not need to "yell"."* Who's yelling? *"jeez."* O_o.  You might want to work on that 'over developed sense of self entitlement' if you intend to get the best from SO.  But hey, your call.  It's no skin off my nose either way..